# Execute AJAX during an unexpected system shutdown

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

Hi i am developing a chat application in which any no of users can chat with a model.Here after the chat tokens will be deducted from the users account at the end of the chat.But this is not going to work when the user closing the browser or unexpected system shutdown instead of clicking the exit chat button.

Please give your valuable feeedback.

Comment: Put a code that will force logout (from serverside) if user have not done activity for some time (example 5 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

for the window closing event you can simply manage the js event `window.onclose`, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclose.

In general, you could log the user last activity (last message get, last post ...) and after a defined timeout remove im of the connected user list.